# Issue with Game Center on Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, game-center

I'm trying to implement Game Center into my game but i have problems with it.

Here is my Main.cs code :

```
namespace iosgame
{       
    public class Application
    {
        [Register ("AppDelegate")]
        public partial class AppDelegate : IOSApplication {

            MainViewController mainViewController;

            public AppDelegate(): base(new Game(new StaticsDatabase(),new StoreDatabase(),new InappPurchase(),new Social(),new MissionsDatabase()), getConfig()) {

            }

            internal static IOSApplicationConfiguration getConfig() {
                IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
                config.orientationLandscape = true;
                config.orientationPortrait = false;
                config.useAccelerometer = false;
                config.useMonotouchOpenTK = true;
                config.useObjectAL = true;
                return config;
            }

            //
            // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
            // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
            // visible.
            //
            // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
            //
            public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
            {
                base.FinishedLaunching(app,options);
                UIViewController controller = ((IOSApplication)Gdx.app).getUIViewController();
                mainViewController = new MainViewController();
                controller.View.Add(mainViewController.View);



                return true;
            }

            private bool isGameCenterAPIAvailable()
            {
                return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (4, 1);
            }
        }

        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the superclass of that Main.cs : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-iosmonotouch/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/ios/IOSApplication.java

I'm trying to use this https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/GameCenterSample/GameCenterSample/MainViewController.cs example but i can't see any authenticate window in my game.I can see "Welcome back ,name" notification but after i log out from gamecenter app and reopen my game but i can't see any authentication window.

How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call this in `FinishedLaunching`:

```
if (!GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated) {
    GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticate (error => {
        if (error != null) 
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error.LocalizedDescription);
    });
}
```

This should display a Game Center "toast" saying "Welcome back, Player 1".

Here are some ideas if this doesn't work:

- Make sure you have setup a new bundle id in the developer portal, and declare it in your `Info.plist`
- Start filling out your app details in iTunes connect (Minimum is description, keywords, icon, 1 screenshot), and make sure to enable Game Center and add your new game to a group
- Login with a test iTunes user in Game Center (create in ITC), or the login associated with your developer account

PS - I wouldn't worry about checking for iOS 4.1, just target iOS 5.0 and higher these days.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm already doing this in my app code.But i have a different problem.I can see "Welcome back, Player 1" toast sometimes but i can't see login window when i log out from Game Center application.I don't have a problem with sample application.

Probably login view is being presented but it's below my own uiview controller.How can game center's auth window know that it will use which uiview to show this login view on that?

Comment: Do you see anything printed on the console from my example above? Any other errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console.This uialertview for auth is being below my iphoneosgameview probably.Here is my base application class:https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-iosmonotouch/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/ios/IOSApplication.java.What i have to add there?

Comment: This must be a private Github repo, I get a 404. Does your app crash? Or does the Game Center logon just not appear? It is a modal view controller that will appear in portrait orientation.

Comment: See my first post for the link:IOSApplication.java.My app doesn't crash.game center login view is not appearing.

Comment: What do you with subclassing?Which class that i must subclass?

Comment: Sorry, I meant replace `iOSApplication` with just `AppDelegate`. If `MainViewController` inherits a Java class, replace it with `UIViewController`.